# Преобразование объектов valueOf и toString

Tags: javascript

Проводя некоторые тесты наткнулся на интересное поведение, которое не могу себе объяснить.

**Код:**

```
var a = {
  toString: function(){return "It's a string"},
  valueOf: function(){return 100}
};
console.log(a); /// Выводит объект (1)
console.log(+a); /// Выводит 100 в числовом типе (2)
console.log(""+a); /// Выводит "100" в строковом типе (3)
console.log(String(a)); /// Выводит "It's a string" (4)
```

**А теперь по порядку:**

1. Под (1) все понятно - должно вывести объект т.к console.log это и делает если ей дают объект.
2. Под (2) cудя по преобразованию типов должно быть числовое преобразование и поэтому должен использоваться valueOf.
3. Под (3) судя по преобразованию типов должно быть строковое преобразование и поэтому должно использоваться toString, но используется valueOf. Почему?
4. Под (4) используется конструктор для преобразования объекта и поэтому срабатывает toString.

**Вопросы:**

Что не так с пунктом 3? Какие ньюансы возникают, что интерпретатор так работает?

P.S Если я где-то не прав, поправьте.

Comment: на сколько я помню для приведения к примитиву обьект кастится сначала методом `valueOf`, тоесть в пункте 3 сначала привели к примитиву, получили `100` , а так как сложение идет со строкой, 100 привели к строке и сложили.

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych Если бы сначала всегда использовался `valueOf` - тогда в 4 примере мы получили бы "100".

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych не совсем так на learn.javascript написано по-другому. То есть там сказано что будет использоваться тот или иной метод в зависимости от контекста.

Comment: В дубликате описан процесс выбора: в каком случае какой метод должен выбираться

Comment: @Grundy довольно непонятен тот алгоритм, нечеловеческим языком написан

Comment: @MaximPro, потому что это псевдокод :) добавил еще один вопрос, как раз с оператором `+`, по ссылке на спецификацию можешь проследить что и как вызывается

Comment: В двух словах. к обоим операндам применяется `ToPrimitive`, который без дополнительных параметров приводит к `number`, отсюда для второго параметра, который в данном случае переменная  `a` - будет вызван `valueOf`

Comment: @Grundy насколько мне известно все арифметические действия приводят операнды к числу. Но только когда `+` это особый случай, и я не понимаю это же прямое преобразование к строке, но методом это игнорируется. Я почитал все что вы скинули, ту спецификацию мне не осилить слишком не понятна она для меня, нужно учиться их читать.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64146/discussion-between-grundy-and-maximpro).

Comment: @MaximPro, ты разобрался почему так происходит?,Я читал дубликат, где Grundy ссылался на спецификацию, но я ее не умею читать)

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный а придется :) Именно там раскрывается детализированное описание механизма. Если говорить вкратце про 3ий пример то там срабатывает алгоритм сложения 2 ух операндов. Но а чтобы их сложить нужно привести их к примитивам, и только после сложить. Алгоритм сложения примитивов описан в спецификации.
И насчет toString и valueOf в спецификации есть описание этих методов. Но скажу опять вкратце в большинстве случаев используется valueOf.
Более подробно нужно читать спецификацию (И то это я вам по памяти рассказал не заглядывая).

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный Впринципе можно было бы подробно расписать алгоритм на пальцах, но это очень долго. Попробуйте почитать спецификацию. Поначалу будет сложно, но после привыкнете.

Comment: @MaximPro спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос о конкатенации решается уже после преобразования обоих операндов в примитивы. Т.е. сначала происходит численное преобразование объекта (т.к. `+` это математический оператор), а уже потом строковое (т.к. второй операнд строка).

Comment: Спорный момент. Поясню. Преобразование к числу: `+a` или `Number(a)`. Преобразование к строке: `"" + a` или `String(a)`. Это кстати написано learn.javascript.

Comment: И кстати когда идет преобразование к числу используется унарный оператор сложения. А вот когда + стоит в контексте сложения двух операндов тут стоит призадуматься.

Comment: Да нет тут спорного момента.